# cakephp : how can i display count for each category?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, count

here is my tables

**brands_tbls**

- `id` `1` `2` `3` `4`
- `name` `Levi's` `Lee` `Woodland` `Spyakr`

**product_tbls**

- `id`
- `brands_tbls_id`
- `product_description`
- `name`
- `price`

I m displaying my brands and also tried for product count by using this code.

**PublicController.php**

```
public function example()
{
    $this->loadModel("Brand");
    $data = $this->Brand->find('all');
    $this->set('brand', $data);
    $this->layout="display";


    $this->loadModel("Product");
    $data = $this->Product->find('count', array('conditions' =>
                                  array('brands_tbls_id' => '1')));
    $this->set('product1', $data);
    $this->layout="display";
}
```

below is my view file

**example.ctp**

```
<?php foreach($brand as $data) : ?>
  <?php foreach($data as $row) : ?>
   <li>
     <a href="#">
        <span class="pull-right">(<?php echo $product1;//--count   ?>)
        </span><?php echo $row["name"];//--brands   ?>
     </a>
   </li>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

by doing this i can get count of product from `product_tbls` where `brands_tbls_id` = `1`

so it will display same product count for all brands.how can i get product count for all brands?

Comment: did you create a model for your `Brands`? what CakePhp version are you in?

Comment: cakephp 2.7.1  and i have model for Brand

Comment: I'd suggest to use a counter cache. There are dozens of duplicates for this question... pick one that you like: **http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcakephp%5D+countercache**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe what you want to achieve is to group your products by brand

```
$data = $this->Product->find(
   'all', 
    array(
        'fields' => array('COUNT(*)'),
        'group' => 'brands_tbls_id',
        'contain' => array('Brand')
   )
);
```

so you can loop through `$data`

Comment: yes when i use `debug($data);` it works and showing correct count for all brands but i don't know how to display.Can you please help me

Answer (score 1):

Your records in $brand is the number of brands you have.

```
<?php echo count($brand); ?>
```

If you want to perform a count on the brands you can do it like this in Cakephp 2.x

```
$data = $this->Brand->find('count');
```

It's a bit unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm displaying brand and products count for the same selected brand